# Kotest: Execution Order of (Nested) Lifecycle Hooks

Tags: kotest

I'm confused about the order in which lifecycle hook in Kotest are executed, especially when it comes to nested tests. Consider the following example:

```kotlin
import io.kotest.core.spec.style.DescribeSpec

class KotestTest : DescribeSpec({
    beforeSpec { println("beforeSpec") }
    afterSpec { println("afterSpec") }
    beforeAny { println("beforeAny") }
    afterAny { println("afterAny") }
    beforeContainer { println("beforeContainer") }
    afterContainer { println("afterContainer") }
    beforeEach { println("beforeEach") }
    afterEach { println("afterEach") }
    beforeTest { println("beforeTest") }
    afterTest { println("afterTest") }
    describe("1") {
        println("1")
        beforeAny { println("beforeAny 1") }
        afterAny { println("afterAny 1") }
        beforeContainer { println("beforeContainer 1") }
        afterContainer { println("afterContainer 1") }
        beforeEach { println("beforeEach 1") }
        afterEach { println("afterEach 1") }
        beforeTest { println("beforeTest 1") }
        afterTest { println("afterTest 1") }
        describe("2") {
            println("2")
            beforeAny { println("beforeAny 2") }
            afterAny { println("afterAny 2") }
            beforeContainer { println("beforeContainer 2") }
            afterContainer { println("afterContainer 2") }
            beforeEach { println("beforeEach 2") }
            afterEach { println("afterEach 2") }
            beforeTest { println("beforeTest 2") }
            afterTest { println("afterTest 2") }
            it("3") { println("3") }
        }
    }
})
```

When I run this test with Kotest 5.4.1, I get the following result:

```
beforeSpec
beforeContainer
beforeAny
beforeTest
1
beforeContainer
beforeContainer 1
beforeAny
beforeAny 1
beforeTest
beforeTest 1
2
beforeEach
beforeEach 1
beforeEach 2
beforeAny
beforeAny 1
beforeAny 2
beforeTest
beforeTest 1
beforeTest 2
3
afterTest
afterTest 1
afterTest 2
afterAny
afterAny 1
afterAny 2
afterEach
afterEach 1
afterEach 2
afterTest
afterTest 1
afterAny
afterAny 1
afterContainer
afterContainer 1
afterTest
afterAny
afterContainer
afterSpec
```

Now for me the following questions arise:

- Is there some documentation or guarantee about the order of `beforeContainer`, `beforeAny` and `beforeTest` resp. `beforeEach`, `beforeAny` and `beforeTest`?
- I understand that the `before` hooks are executed from outside to inside, but would expect the `after` hooks to then be executed in the reverse order, i.e., from inside to outside. Is this a bug?

Motivation: We wanted to verify mock invocations like

```kotlin
val mock = mockk<MyClass>()

afterEach { confirmVerified(mock); clearMocks(mock); }

describe("fun1") {
    beforeEach { every { mock.fun1()} returns 1 }
    afterEach { verify { mock.fun1()} }

    it("...") {...}
}
```

but due to the execution order the outer `afterEach` gets executed first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of lifecycle hooks in Kotest is confusing because one would expect that they register the hooks somewhere inside a scoped context, but instead it is registered in the spec.

You can check this by calling

```
println(registeredExtensions())
```

in any test case. The function `registeredExtensions()` gives you the list of all extensions that are registered in your spec, and that list will contain `BeforeX` and `AfterX` extensions in the same order, you called functions `beforeX` and `afterX`, respectively.

The problem here is that all extensions are always executed in the order they are registered. This is okay for all before-functions, but is not okay for the after-functions.

The simplest way I found to solve this, is to write a `TestCaseExtension` that allows to wrap something around the execution of each test:

```
class NestedAfter(
    private val descriptor: Descriptor,
    private val afterTest: AfterTest,
    private val type: TestType? = null,
) : TestCaseExtension {
    override suspend fun intercept(testCase: TestCase, execute: suspend (TestCase) -> TestResult): TestResult {
        return execute(testCase).also { testResult ->
            if ((type == null || type == testCase.type) && descriptor.isAncestorOf(testCase.descriptor))
                afterTest(Tuple2(testCase, testResult))
        }
    }
}
```

The extension executes each test and after that it conditionally calls the `afterTest` function. Since all extensions are called in order of their registration, each subsequent `NestedAfter` is wrapped inside preceding `NestedAfter` calls - leading to a proper nesting and the execution order we are expecting.

The condition `descriptor.isAncestorOf(testCase.descriptor)` makes sure that we call the `afterTest` function only for test cases that are (possibly nested) inside the test where we defined the extension.

This would still be quite cumbersome to use, so we also define the following functions:

```
fun TestScope.nestedAfterAny(afterTest: AfterTest) {
    testCase.spec.extension(NestedAfter(testCase.descriptor, afterTest))
}
fun TestScope.nestedAfterEach(afterTest: AfterTest) {
    testCase.spec.extension(NestedAfter(testCase.descriptor, afterTest, TestType.Test))
}
fun TestScope.nestedAfterContainer(afterTest: AfterTest) {
    testCase.spec.extension(NestedAfter(testCase.descriptor, afterTest, TestType.Container))
}
```

These function makes sure to register an instance of our extension accompanied by the descriptor of the `TestCase` that is currently running.

Now, if we want to have the expected execution order, then we can use `nestedAfterAny` instead of `afterAny`, `nestedAfterContainer` instead of `afterContainer` and `nestedAfterEach` instead of `afterEach`.

You can then write the following inside your test class, and the functions will respect the nesting of your test cases:

```
val mock = mockk<MyClass>()
describe("root") {
    nestedAfterEach { confirmVerified(mock); clearMocks(mock); }

    describe("fun1") {
        beforeEach { every { mock.fun1() } returns 1 }
        nestedAfterEach { verify { mock.fun1() } }

        it("...") {
            mock.fun1()
        }
    }
}
```

---

Note that we can call the `nestedAfterX` functions only inside `TestContext` which is why I introduced the `describe("root")` container in the example above.

If we want to get rid of that limitation, we can alter the `NestedAfter` class to have a nullable `descriptor` and consequently change the condition to `descriptor == null || descriptor.isAncestorOf(testCase.descriptor)`.

Then we can define functions

```
fun DslDrivenSpec.nestedAfterAny(afterTest: AfterTest) {
    extension(NestedAfter(null, afterTest))
}

fun DslDrivenSpec.nestedAfterEach(afterTest: AfterTest) {
    extension(NestedAfter(null, afterTest, TestType.Test))
}

fun DslDrivenSpec.nestedAfterContainer(afterTest: AfterTest) {
    extension(NestedAfter(null, afterTest, TestType.Container))
}
```

which allow to define `nestedAfterX` functions on the root level.

Then we can alter your `KotestTest` from above to look like this:

```
class KotestTest : DescribeSpec({
    beforeSpec { println("beforeSpec") }
    afterSpec { println("afterSpec") }
    beforeAny { println("beforeAny") }
    nestedAfterAny { println("afterAny") }
    beforeContainer { println("beforeContainer") }
    nestedAfterContainer { println("afterContainer") }
    beforeEach { println("beforeEach") }
    nestedAfterEach { println("afterEach") }
    beforeTest { println("beforeTest") }
    nestedAfterEach { println("afterTest") }
    describe("1") {
        println("1")
        beforeAny { println("beforeAny 1") }
        nestedAfterAny { println("afterAny 1") }
        beforeContainer { println("beforeContainer 1") }
        nestedAfterContainer { println("afterContainer 1") }
        beforeEach { println("beforeEach 1") }
        nestedAfterEach { println("afterEach 1") }
        beforeTest { println("beforeTest 1") }
        nestedAfterEach { println("afterTest 1") }
        describe("2") {
            println("2")
            beforeAny { println("beforeAny 2") }
            nestedAfterAny { println("afterAny 2") }
            beforeContainer { println("beforeContainer 2") }
            nestedAfterContainer { println("afterContainer 2") }
            beforeEach { println("beforeEach 2") }
            nestedAfterEach { println("afterEach 2") }
            beforeTest { println("beforeTest 2") }
            nestedAfterEach { println("afterTest 2") }
            it("3") { println("3") }
        }
    }
})
```

The output of this test where we replaced all `after` functions with `nestedAfter` functions (except for `afterSpec` where it is not necessary) looks like this:

```
beforeSpec
beforeContainer
beforeAny
beforeTest
1
beforeContainer
beforeContainer 1
beforeAny
beforeAny 1
beforeTest
beforeTest 1
2
beforeEach
beforeEach 1
beforeEach 2
beforeAny
beforeAny 1
beforeAny 2
beforeTest
beforeTest 1
beforeTest 2
3
afterTest 2
afterEach 2
afterAny 2
afterTest 1
afterEach 1
afterAny 1
afterTest
afterEach
afterAny
afterContainer 1
afterAny 1
afterContainer
afterAny
afterContainer
afterAny
afterSpec
```

Also please note that `afterTest` is only a *soft-deprecated* synonym of `afterEach` which is why I did not provide a nested counterpart for it.